# Android Studio emulator Not Running After Reinstallation

Tags: android-studio

I am Korean.

A few days ago, the Wi-Fi on the emulator was weird,
so I reinstalled my Android studio from 2022.2 to 2022.3.

Then this error occurred. "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_34 has terminated."

To tell you the specifications of my laptop
My laptop specification is AMD Ryzen 55600H, RTX 3060.

The solutions I have tried so far are reinstall Sdk,
make sure that the path to install Sdk is not in Korean, and set environment variables.

And I installed the Android Emulator hypervisor driver on Sdk tools because HAXM will make errors on this laptop.

And the windows feature has HAXM and Windows hypervisor platform features turned off.

And I also checked that AMD-V Technology is enabled in the Bios setting.

Below I will attach my execution log. There are some unencoded characters, but I don't think it's an important part.

I hope this problem can be solved in any way.

```
> 2023-12-10 13:15:13,957 [ 523212]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe
> -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_34 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 2023-12-10 13:15:13,984 [ 523239]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Android emulator version
> 33.1.23.0 (build_id 11150993) (CL:N/A) 2023-12-10 13:15:13,984 [ 523239]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Found systemPath
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
> 2023-12-10 13:15:14,045 [ 523300]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.045:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\5ae737eb-1561-4f39-9755-c84aa6573ccb:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:14,045 [ 523300]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.045:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\3783dea1-f202-4387-9de4-66ff4093d2cb:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:14,046 [ 523301]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.046:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\8bef8969-9f6b-492c-8b77-9111d4f29df3:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:14,046 [ 523301]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.046:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\084d7f9c-7527-4b7a-86e6-3c3ee5a60d9d:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:14,046 [ 523301]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.046:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\17de164f-dabd-40d5-b361-8a55ffed973a:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) . . . 2023-12-10 13:15:14,058 [
> 523313]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.058:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\fbd71c7c-0746-4581-a6d9-069a2f30da5c:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:14,058 [ 523313]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.058:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\1b6dd3dc-da87-48e3-91ac-0d2e46ac0dac:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:14,058 [ 523313]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.058:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\79765249-98b1-41f0-b0fd-4dd086ba342a:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:14,059 [ 523314]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131514.059:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\0c8dc403-6bf5-43a8-9c7a-abcb1241bbf5:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:15,247 [ 524502]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address:
> f074:3864:9701:0:45:3864:9701:0 (2x) 2023-12-10 13:15:15,247 [ 524502]
> WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Failed to process .ini file
> C:\Users\oowgn\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_2_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini
> for reading. 2023-12-10 13:15:15,466 [ 524721]   INFO - Emulator:
> Pixel 2 API 34 - I1210 13:15:15.466353    3944 HealthMonitor.cpp:279]
> HealthMonitor disabled. 2023-12-10 13:15:15,467 [ 524722]   INFO -
> Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - added library vulkan-1.dll 2023-12-10
> 13:15:15,692 [ 524947]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:7472:20231210,131515.692:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\5ae737eb-1561-4f39-9755-c84aa6573ccb:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:15,692 [ 524947]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:7472:20231210,131515.692:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\3783dea1-f202-4387-9de4-66ff4093d2cb:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:15,693 [ 524948]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:7472:20231210,131515.693:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\8bef8969-9f6b-492c-8b77-9111d4f29df3:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:15,693 [ 524948]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:7472:20231210,131515.693:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\084d7f9c-7527-4b7a-86e6-3c3ee5a60d9d:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:15,693 [ 524948]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:7472:20231210,131515.693:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\17de164f-dabd-40d5-b361-8a55ffed973a:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) . . . 2023-12-10 13:15:17,316 [
> 526571]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131517.316:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\1b6dd3dc-da87-48e3-91ac-0d2e46ac0dac:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:17,317 [ 526572]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131517.317:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\79765249-98b1-41f0-b0fd-4dd086ba342a:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:17,317 [ 526572]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131517.317:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\0c8dc403-6bf5-43a8-9c7a-abcb1241bbf5:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:17,317 [ 526572]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 -
> [15840:12420:20231210,131517.317:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\oowgn\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.23.db\attachments\185af66a-f023-4853-a1e6-70444294c484:
> 吏��젙�맂 �뙆�씪�쓣 李얠쓣 �닔 �뾾�뒿�땲�떎. (2) 2023-12-10 13:15:17,382 [ 526637]  
> INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Process finished with exit code
> 1073741845 2023-12-10 13:15:18,001 [ 527256]   WARN -
> #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_2_API_34 is online, assuming it's not
```

Comment: This is happening while starting `Android Studio` or `Emulator`? You mentioned in the Title `Android Studio is not running` and the below log is about `Emulator` crashes.

Comment: It's an emulator.

Comment: "A google search of "chromium filesystem_win.cc GetFileAttributes" shows the same error for lots of other Chromium based software like nw.js and opera, so this is not an issue of Electron and I'm closing this issue.", see: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35448#issuecomment-1232899297  (and YES, i know that that is not an answer...)

Comment: Unbelievably just adding the advancedFeatures.ini file worked out. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Hi, suddenly I have the same error! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77790408/the-emulator-process-for-avd-pixel-6-pro-api-33-has-terminated-error-nothing-so] Where did you add the advancedFeatures.ini file?