# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6_Pro_API_33 has terminated. Error nothing solved with many try

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I have this error and tried all of the solutions on the post
[Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)
but suddenly still I have the error and the emulator not working.
On the log file, I have these results:

> 2024-01-10 03:19:33,282 [ 124664]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API
> 33 - D:\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd
> Pixel_6_Pro_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout
> 300 2024-01-10 03:19:33,420 [ 124802]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro
> API 33 - [23876:9252:20240110,031933.420:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\5358b1c5-f593-435a-93b4-1c00b379ff31:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,420
> [ 124802]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23876:9252:20240110,031933.420:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\b1a477a4-d28d-46c8-b2b5-ebcb592a9313:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,420
> [ 124802]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23876:9252:20240110,031933.420:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\a888ef73-a80c-4d8b-9ec3-8cb178789652:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,421
> [ 124803]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23876:9252:20240110,031933.421:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\7b8bc835-3d66-49e6-a0e8-8b18d66a3e65:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,421
> [ 124803]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23876:9252:20240110,031933.421:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\824f6b32-7756-41f0-a8e0-75040ade9e5d:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,421
> [ 124803]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23876:9252:20240110,031933.421:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\9c6441a0-458d-4f39-ad4c-e37d5fb4b0b1:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,421
> [ 124803]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23876:9252:20240110,031933.421:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\38d56513-62d4-4dd4-bf25-c62b5ad82827:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,422
> [ 124804]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23876:9252:20240110,031933.422:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\30765fcd-07e8-4797-98ee-8ba1fb56d373:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,445
> [ 124827]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Storing crashdata
> in:
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db,
> detection is enabled for process: 12708 2024-01-10 03:19:33,445 [
> 124827]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Android emulator
> version 34.2.2.0 (build_id 11257478) (CL:N/A) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,445
> [ 124827]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Found systemPath
> D:\sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\ 2024-01-10
> 03:19:33,552 [ 124934]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.552:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\5358b1c5-f593-435a-93b4-1c00b379ff31:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,552
> [ 124934]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.552:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\b1a477a4-d28d-46c8-b2b5-ebcb592a9313:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,552
> [ 124934]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.552:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\a888ef73-a80c-4d8b-9ec3-8cb178789652:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,553
> [ 124935]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.552:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\7b8bc835-3d66-49e6-a0e8-8b18d66a3e65:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,553
> [ 124935]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.553:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\824f6b32-7756-41f0-a8e0-75040ade9e5d:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,553
> [ 124935]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.553:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\9c6441a0-458d-4f39-ad4c-e37d5fb4b0b1:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,554
> [ 124936]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.554:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\38d56513-62d4-4dd4-bf25-c62b5ad82827:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,554
> [ 124936]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.554:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\30765fcd-07e8-4797-98ee-8ba1fb56d373:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,819
> [ 125201]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.819:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\5358b1c5-f593-435a-93b4-1c00b379ff31:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,820
> [ 125202]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.819:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\b1a477a4-d28d-46c8-b2b5-ebcb592a9313:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,820
> [ 125202]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.819:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\a888ef73-a80c-4d8b-9ec3-8cb178789652:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,820
> [ 125202]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.820:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\7b8bc835-3d66-49e6-a0e8-8b18d66a3e65:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,820
> [ 125202]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.820:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\824f6b32-7756-41f0-a8e0-75040ade9e5d:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,820
> [ 125202]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.820:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\9c6441a0-458d-4f39-ad4c-e37d5fb4b0b1:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,820
> [ 125202]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.820:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\38d56513-62d4-4dd4-bf25-c62b5ad82827:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,820
> [ 125202]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:18392:20240110,031933.820:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\30765fcd-07e8-4797-98ee-8ba1fb56d373:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,847
> [ 125229]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.847:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\5358b1c5-f593-435a-93b4-1c00b379ff31:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,848
> [ 125230]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.848:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\b1a477a4-d28d-46c8-b2b5-ebcb592a9313:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,848
> [ 125230]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.848:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\a888ef73-a80c-4d8b-9ec3-8cb178789652:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,848
> [ 125230]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.848:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\7b8bc835-3d66-49e6-a0e8-8b18d66a3e65:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,848
> [ 125230]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.848:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\824f6b32-7756-41f0-a8e0-75040ade9e5d:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,848
> [ 125230]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.848:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\9c6441a0-458d-4f39-ad4c-e37d5fb4b0b1:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,849
> [ 125231]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.848:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\38d56513-62d4-4dd4-bf25-c62b5ad82827:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,849
> [ 125231]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.849:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\30765fcd-07e8-4797-98ee-8ba1fb56d373:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,849
> [ 125231]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.849:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\68a98467-c073-4c24-96bb-6d9751e7f5b6:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,850
> [ 125232]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.850:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\5358b1c5-f593-435a-93b4-1c00b379ff31:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,850
> [ 125232]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.850:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\b1a477a4-d28d-46c8-b2b5-ebcb592a9313:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,850
> [ 125232]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.850:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\a888ef73-a80c-4d8b-9ec3-8cb178789652:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,851
> [ 125233]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.851:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\7b8bc835-3d66-49e6-a0e8-8b18d66a3e65:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,851
> [ 125233]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.851:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\824f6b32-7756-41f0-a8e0-75040ade9e5d:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,851
> [ 125233]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.851:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\9c6441a0-458d-4f39-ad4c-e37d5fb4b0b1:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,851
> [ 125233]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.851:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\38d56513-62d4-4dd4-bf25-c62b5ad82827:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,851
> [ 125233]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.851:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\30765fcd-07e8-4797-98ee-8ba1fb56d373:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,851
> [ 125233]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 -
> [23664:6804:20240110,031933.851:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
> GetFileAttributes
> C:\Users\Ebarge\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.2.db\attachments\68a98467-c073-4c24-96bb-6d9751e7f5b6:
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2) 2024-01-10 03:19:33,858
> [ 125240]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Process finished
> with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

What are the files requested on the "attachments" folder that are empty and how I can resolve them?

Answer (score 0):

You left my question and answer your question

I want C:/Users/{UserName}/.android to create the advancedFeatures.ini file in the path, open it with a notepad, and then

```
Vulkan = on
GLDirectMem = on
```

I inserted this

Maybe this answer will solve your error

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I saw your question after I added my question. I did this before but still have the error, only I can use physical devices for testing....:(